Ruby Gem Thor 1.3 failed to work with Terminal-Table
Since I updated the Thor Gem from 1.2.2 to 1.3.2 and I see this error on Terminal-Table in my script.
uninitialized constant Thor::Shell::Terminal::Table (NameError)
Anyone would shed some light on how to resolve this?
ruby 3.3.6
MacOS Homebrew
Here is a sample code
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'bundler/inline'

gemfile do
  source 'https://rubygems.org'

  gem 'thor', '1.3.2'  # 1.2.2 # works fine
  gem 'terminal-table'
end

class TodoCLI < Thor
  # Define a default task
  default_task :help

  desc "sim", "simulation"
  def sim
    data = [
      { name: 'Alice', age: 30, city: 'New York' },
      { name: 'Bob', age: 25, city: 'Los Angeles' },
      { name: 'Charlie', age: 35, city: 'Chicago' }
    ]
    table = Terminal::Table.new(
      header: %w[Name Age City], # Column headers
      rows: data.map { |row| [row[:name], row[:age], row[:city]] } # Data rows
    )

    puts table.render
  end
end

TodoCLI.start(ARGV)


The issue appears to be that Thor 1.3.0 introduced a class Thor::Shell::Terminal. Source
So when you call Terminal::Table inside TodoCLI  the Terminal constant is resolving to Thor::Shell::Terminal, which does not have a nested Table class.
The resolution is very simple. Just change Terminal::Table to reference the TOPLEVEL scope ::Terminal::Table and it should resolve just fine.
